# merge two comma separeted column in an array mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two column in my database column1 and column2 as

```
   column1                   column2
 0,1,2,3,4,5,6       112, 225, 241, 85, 32, 36
```

I want to fetch these column in array like below

```
Array(
[0] => 112
[1] => 225
[2] => 241
[3] => 85
[4] => 32
[5] => 36 )
```

how to do this in mysql query please help me. thanks in advance....

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: a single query or a mysql function to get such type of result..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(`column1`, ',' ,`column2`) as t1 FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_fetch_array` method:

```
$a = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $a[$row["column1"]] = $row["column2"];
}
```

Comment: I want query in mysql for this.

Comment: try this SELECT CONCAT(`column1`, ' ', `column2`) FROM `tablename`